# SQL query for x- dates before and after a given date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to extract x-days before and after a given date range. I have formulated the query as follows

```
SELECT a,b,date FROM table.test 
 WHERE date < "2012-09-07" - INTERVAL 2 DAY 
   AND date > "2012-09-08"  + INTERVAL 2
```

The other approach which was NOT BETWEEN method also. None of them seems to be giving me right answer.  The `date` is of type `varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL` within the database

Sample Data

```
a b date
2 4 2012-09-07
3 2 2012-09-05
5 3 2012-09-08
7 4 2012-09-07
8 5 2012-09-06
9 6 2012-09-07
3 7 2012-09-09
```

What I am looking for it the following:

```
a b date
3 2 2012-09-05
3 7 2012-09-09
```

The `date` is of type `varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL` within the database

Comment: Is there any reason why your date on the database isn't a date field?

Comment: I'm just pulling the data from the DB. I too had the same issue

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for this:

```
SELECT a,b,date 
  FROM table.test 
 WHERE date < str_to_date('2012-09-07', '%Y-%m-%d')  - INTERVAL 2 DAY 
    OR date > str_to_date('2012-09-08', '%Y-%m-%d')  + INTERVAL 2 DAY;
```

Mainly, the `AND` needs to replaced by `OR`. I'd prefer an expicit (date) type conversion as well.

**Update**: re-reading your question carefully, the statement above might not be the one you are looking for. If Gordon go it right and if you want to use `BETWEEN` you might go for:

```
SELECT a,b,date 
  FROM table.test 
 WHERE date BETWEEN str_to_date('2012-09-07', '%Y-%m-%d')  - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND
                    str_to_date('2012-09-08', '%Y-%m-%d')  + INTERVAL 2 DAY 
   AND date NOT BETWEEN str_to_date('2012-09-07', '%Y-%m-%d') AND
                        str_to_date('2012-09-08', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

This is basically the same.

Comment: I understood your query. But, strangely, I get '2012-11-13 12:31:10'
`'2013-01-11 04:43:35'
'2012-10-09 14:40:58'
'2015-07-22 14:49:34'
'2014-07-12 11:20:02'
'2013-04-17 21:33:16'
'2012-10-26 10:02:51'
'2013-09-05 08:28:54'
'2015-06-01 13:47:32'
'2012-10-20 17:17:25'
'2015-11-23 00:49:47'
'2015-10-19 04:36:35'
'2014-05-21 08:27:10'
'2013-06-17 00:37:23'
'2014-09-15 13:11:47'`. I have just replicated your query on my mysql workbench.

Comment: Reading carefully again, I think Gordon Linoff is on the right track, Isn't he? Though I'm still not a friend of implicit type conversions ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just have your comparisons backwards:

```
SELECT a, b, date
FROM table.test 
WHERE (date >= '2012-09-07' - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND
       date < '2012-09-07'
      ) OR
      (date > '2012-09-08' AND
       date <= '2012-09-08' + INTERVAL 2
      );
```

I'm not sure if you want `>`/`<` or `>=`/`<=`.